# detect cd/dvd in cd drive and play on window media player

Tags: c#, winforms

on my window forms I have created a button on my application. when I click the button it will check if there is any CD/DVD in the CD drive. If there is a CD/DVD in the CD drive, the media player will start the video media on windows media player i have add to the application.

So far, I have been only able to create the open dialog to select from the CD and play them.
Can anyone advice me on what I should use to detect the CD media in the drive?

EDIT://sorry i am not great with C# so can you guys explain on the tutorials you provided?

```
    private void Runbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.mediaCollection.getByName("mediafile");


    }

    private void Stopbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop();

    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24544/Burning-and-Erasing-CD-DVD-Blu-ray-Media-with-C-an).

Comment: Doesn't the operating system do this already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work: (it is in C++, use DllImport to make Win32 API calls - explained [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1285/Calling-API-functions-using-C))

```
char szDrives[MAX_PATH];      
long TotalNumberOfFreeBytes  = 0;
long FreeBytesAvailable = 0;

// Get all the drives on your system. Divide by 4 as strlen("C:\") ==  4
int noOfDrives =(GetLogicalDriveStrings(MAX_PATH,szDrives)/4);

for(int i=0;i<noOfDrives ;i++)
{
   // find CD ROM drives
   if (DRIVE_CDROM == GetDriveType(&drivestr[i*4]))
   {  
          if(!GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(&drivestr[i*4],
               &FreeBytesAvailable,
               NULL,
               &TotalNumberOfFreeBytes  ))
          {
             // Disk in drive, enumerate files 
             // using FindFirstFile/FindNextFile
             // and play video if any
          }
   }
}
```

The GetDiskFreeSpaceEx function returns zero (0) for TotalNumberOfFreeBytes and FreeBytesAvailable for all CD requests unless the disk is an unwritten CD in a CD-RW drive.

Comment: Thanks for your response however i am using C# on visual studio. - @Flot2011

Comment: @TonySstark: as I said you can call these functions from C# using DllImport. See link in my answer.